# Potentially damaged US passport - okay to travel on?

Tags: usa, passports

I'm a US citizen studying abroad in England and have to carry around my passport wherever I go (lost my state ID while traveling). Because of this, the first page has peeled off from the cover of the book. Do you think this would be an issue with travel? Note: the ID page (laminated page) is in perfect condition.

Here are some pictures:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have travelled with passports in much worse shapes (non-US).. I was fine

Comment: There is no requirement to carry ID on you in the United Kingdom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Department of State](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/FAQs.html) advises:

> If your passport has been significantly damaged, especially the book cover or the page displaying your personal data and photo, you will need to apply for a new passport.  Conditions that may constitute damage requiring you to replace your passport include water damage, a significant tear, unofficial markings on the data page, missing visa pages (torn out), a hole punch, or other injuries.
>
> Normal wear of a U.S. passport is expected and likely does not constitute "damage."  For instance normal wear includes the bend of a passport after being carried in your back pocket or fanning of the visa pages after extensive opening and closing.

"other injuries" is vague but with nothing missing or illegible I think you should be "OK".

Comment: Thanks; due to this response and the comment on my OP, I'll travel on it. I'll be sure to post back once I succeed or fail.

Comment: Update many months later:

I was able to travel on it completely. I did get a clear case for it which I tucked the outer cover into to not make it as obvious that the book was coming undone. There were a couple times where I was held up and they asked me extra questions; they seemed concerned with the legitimacy of the book. After returning to America I got a new one, though realistically I likely could've gone a bit longer

Comment: @matthewgrossman you should post that as an answer.